# Export data to CSV file using PHP - output is empty

Tags: php, csv, export-to-csv

I thought it will be easy task, but simple I'm not able to output data from an array to CSV file (saved on a server).

Code for that part looks like:

```
$fp = fopen('missing-skus.csv', 'w');

foreach ($missing_array as $lines) {
    fputcsv($fp, $lines);
}

fclose($fp);
```

`$missing_array` looks like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 5804
    [1] => 5803
    [2] => 5802
    [3] => 5801
    [4] => 5800
    [5] => 5799
    [6] => 5798
    [7] => 5797
    [8] => 5796
    [9] => 5795
    [10] => 5794
    [11] => 5793
    [12] => 5792
    [13] => 5791
    [14] => 5790
    [15] => 5789
    [16] => 5788
    [17] => 5787
    [18] => 5786
    [19] => 5785
    [20] => 5784
    [21] => 5783
    [22] => 5782
    [23] => 5781
    [24] => 5780
    [25] => 5779
)
```

No matter what, file is always blank.  Any clue what I have missed?

Comment: Does the server have write access to that file? You can also use `'php://output'` as the filename to output to the browser as a test.

Comment: Yes, it does - an example from http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php works fine.

Comment: The second arg to `fputscsv` is an array of fileds.  You are passing a string or int.

Comment: Have you tried: `fputcsv($fp, array($lines));`. The second param should be an array, even if you only have 1 column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second argument to `fputcsv` is an array of fields. You are passing a string or integer.

If you want one line with the array values as fields, in CSV fashion, then just:

```
$fp = fopen('missing-skus.csv', 'w');
fputcsv($fp, $missing_array);
```

If you just want each array value on one line then no need for `fputcsv`:

```
file_put_contents('missing-skus.csv', implode("\n", $missing_array));
```

Comment: That works as well jerremyharris solution to use `fputcsv($fp, array($lines));`

Comment: Yes, but why open a file loop through an array and use `fputcsv` to write one item to each line and then close the file?